# Change toolbar and tabs background on tab change

Tags: android, tabs, android-toolbar, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have an app with the new Toolbar (that replaces the ActionBar) and tabs (currently using [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)).

I have 3 tabs, and I want to translate the color while changing the tab.
For example, for tab1 have the Toolbar and tabs show #ff0000, for tab2 #00ff00 and for tab3 #0000ff.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (mPreviousSelectedPage != position) {
                int currentColor =((MyFragment) mAdapter.getItemAt(position)).getColor();
                position = mPreviousSelectedPage > position? position - 1; position + 1;
                if(position < mViewPage.getCount()-1 && position >=0){
                    ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mToolbar, "backgroundColor", mPreviousColor, currentColor);
                    colorAnim.setDuration(100);
                    colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                    colorAnim.start();
                    mPreviousSelectedPage = position;
                    mPreviousColor = currentColor;
              }
            }
        }
```

Your fragments in your `ViewPagerAdapter` should have method `getColor()` that will return the color associated with that fragment.

`ValueAnimator` and `ArgbEvaluator` will do the animation between the two colors. If you want to use the color in more views, set `AnimationUpdateListener` and set the color to the views.